# How to only trigger once for revenue analytic in Unity IAP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity built-in IAP, the callback for `ProcessPurchase()` is being called on first-time subscription and a restored purchase. I want to implement revenue analytic using other SDK.

My question is where do I put exactly the code so that it is only trigger on a real purchase, but not on restore purchase,etc.

I am using fabric for the revenue. Did I put fabric API at the right place?

```
public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) 
{
    bool validPurchase = true;

    if (ReceiptSupport)
    {
        // Presume valid for platforms with no R.V.
        // Unity IAP's validation logic is only included on these platforms.

        #if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX

        //  Prepare the validator with the secrets we prepared in the Editor
        //      obfuscation window.

        var validator = new CrossPlatformValidator(GooglePlayTangle.Data(), AppleTangle.Data(), Application.identifier);
        try
        {
            // On Google Play, result has a single product ID.
            // On Apple stores, receipts contain multiple products.

            var result = validator.Validate(args.purchasedProduct.receipt);

            // For informational purposes, we list the receipt(s)
            Debug.Log("Receipt is valid. Contents:");

            foreach (IPurchaseReceipt productReceipt in result)
            {
                Debug.Log(productReceipt.productID);
                Debug.Log(productReceipt.purchaseDate);
                Debug.Log(productReceipt.transactionID);
            }

            // Fabric purchase tracking
            Answers.LogPurchase (
                args.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedPrice,
                args.purchasedProduct.metadata.isoCurrencyCode,
                (result != null ? true : false),
                args.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedTitle,
                args.purchasedProduct.definition.type.ToString(),
                args.purchasedProduct.transactionID,
                null
            );
        }
        catch (IAPSecurityException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Invalid receipt, not unlocking content. SUPER PROBLEM");
            validPurchase = false;
        }
        #endif
    }

    // Or ... a subscription product has been purchased by this user.
    if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDSubscription1, StringComparison.Ordinal) && validPurchase)
    {
        waitingPurchaseScreen.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        OnPurchaseDone(1);
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDSubscription2, StringComparison.Ordinal) && validPurchase)
    {
        waitingPurchaseScreen.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        OnPurchaseDone(2);
    }
    // Or ... an unknown product has been purchased by this user. Fill in additional products here.
    else 
    {
    //if (OnPurchaseFail != null)
    //    OnPurchaseFail.Invoke();
        waitingPurchaseScreen.SetActive(false);
        PlayFabManager.Instance.SetSubscription(false);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Subscribed", 0);
        Debug.Log("SSS Cancel");
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
    }
    // Return a flag indicating wither this product has completely been received, or if the application needs to be reminded of this purchase at next app launch. Is useful when saving purchased products to the cloud, and when that save is delayed.
    return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not experienced with in-app-purchases, but since no one else gave you a reply, I share what I searched around to find and my thoughts on it.

> My question is where do I put exactly the code so that it is only trigger on a real purchase, but not on restore purchase,etc.

It would seem that it HAS to be called on restore purchases and that the IAP does this automatically, as they use it to unlock the purchased items.

**Android and Windows platform**

"On platforms that support it (e.g. Google Play and Universal Windows Applications) Unity IAP automatically restores any products the user owns during the first initialization following reinstallation; **the ProcessPurchase method of your IStoreListener will be called for each owned item.**"

**Apple**

"On Apple platforms users must enter their password to retrieve previous transactions so your application must provide users with a button letting them do so. During this process **the ProcessPurchase method of your IStoreListener will be invoked for any items the user already owns.**"

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPRestoringTransactions.html

---

However, it also seems that the Unity IAP provides receipts.

These receipts contain a payload that you may be able to use to check whether or not it is a new purchase.

[image: UnityIAPReceipts]

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPPurchaseReceipts.html

I hope this can somehow bring you a bit further.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I check your link and also do more research, but I failed to get information that allow me to differentiate a new purchase. Either the data is not enough or I have no idea to put together the logic. I extract more data follow by link below, but non of them is useful.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPValidatingReceipts.html

Answer (score 1):

Necroing this post to add my own solution to this problem!

Using Unity IAP's `IStoreListener` interface, we should be able to use the following to find purchase receipts before ProcessPurchase is called to restore purchases:

```
public class UnityIAPPurchaser : IStoreListener {
    private string[] _ownedSKUs;
    
    // Called by UnityPurchasing.Initialize(...)
    void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions) {
        _ownedSKUs = controller.products.all
            .Where(p => p.hasReceipt)
            .Select(p => p.definition.storeSpecificId)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

From here, you can just check `_ownedSKUs.Contains(sku)` in ProcessPurchase before sending your analytics events.

In my own testing, ProcessPurchases are always called after OnInitialized. Hopefully this helps! I would love if there were a better solution too.